# Certificate from Trusted List of CA not returned by server to client

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a W2K8 R2 SP1 server hosting an SSL web site requiring client certificate. We have a root certificate (self signed), saved in local machine trusted CA store. On client, browser asks for a client certificate and it works fine.

Now, we have another root certificate that is also saved in local machine trusted CA store. Problem is that the browser does not offer to choose client certificate issued by this root CA.

Reason why browser does not prompt is that server is configured (default option) to return a list of trusted root CA to the client to help it limit the list of client certificates to choose from. If we configure the server so that it does not provide this list  (HKLM/system/currentcontrolset/control/securityproviders/schannel/sendtrustedissuerlist=0), the browser has not clue and displays all client certificates and then it works fine.

We had a problem like this in the past because the list of trusted CA was too long and thus was truncated when returned to the client but it's not the case here, only 8 trusted CAs are returned.

Also, if I register this new root CA on another (very similar) server, there it works fine, returned trusted list contains the new CA.

I'm really out of clue why this specific server refuses to return my root CA in the list during SSL negotiation, can someone help please ???

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps you or someone else but according to Microsoft and their Windows Server 2012 documentation your problem seems to be related to this:

"If the **Trusted Root Certifictation Authorities** store that was used contains a mix of Root (self-signed) and certification authority (CA) Issuer certificates, only the CA Issuer certificates will be sent to the server by default".

Keep on mind that you may use different store for "Certificate Trust List" (CTL). "**Client Authentication Issuer**" store is being checked/used first (by default on Windows Server 2012) and then if empty "**Trusted Root Certifictation Authorities**" store.

If you were on 2012, you could have manually configured CTL store, but I don't think that option was present on 2008 R2 (though I might be mistaken).